# Integrated AngularJS + Rails or separated Angular + Rails API-only (microservices architecture)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, architecture, microservices, saas

As I understand it, there are two common approaches to running AngularJS (or ReactJS, VueJS etc. same idea...).

1. Integrate the AngularJS front-end into a Rails application (as in [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-rails))
2. Run an AngularJS application which communicates with a completely separate Rails API-only back-end a.k.a: microservices architecture (as in [this tutorial](https://www.angularonrails.com/getting-started-with-angular-and-rails/))

Which approach would be most appropriate from a Software as a Service stand-point?

Comment: I prefer the second approach due two main reasons:

1) Price and scalabity - Amazon S3 is very cheap to deliver static files sites, so if you are planning to deploy it in a docker environment or in a host, maybe it will cost a litle more.
2) Product development - With these things separated, will be more easy to update the frameworks or something if it needed (like upgrade from Rails 4 to Rails 5), or just modify the business rules.

Just one suggestion:

If you will use this approach, please take a look on integrations tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt the second approach. 
It's more suitable, simple and convenient.
 Also it will reduce the complexities which you will face when you will integrate AngularJs as front-end in your Rails Application. Also you can test the application easily